# Can ELMAH be used in Xamarin solutions?

Tags: exception, android-studio, xamarin, elmah, elmah.mvc

Reading [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) today, and probably embarking on a Xamarin solution very soon (the other possibility is "going native" with just Android, using Android Studio), I got to wondering:

Can ELMAH be used in Xamarin solutions?

And, in fact, if the road less taken (Android Studio) is chosen, what tool is there for Android/Java projects that that most closely resembles ELMAH's advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is very specifically targeted for ASP.NET.

Error/crash logging solutions for Xamarin include [Raygun](http://raygun.io/), [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/), and [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com).

Comment: Do you recommend any of them? Which, if any, do you use?

Comment: I use TestFlight for deployment, but haven't used any of them for exception logging.  Tool recommendations are generally considered Off Topic on SO

Comment: If you're looking for an officially supported crash reporting plugin for Xamarin, Crittercism just released one (Disclaimer: I'm one of the co-founders).  You can download it from the Xamarin store here: http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

Comment: You can use Xamarin.Insights http://insights.xamarin.com/ for catching up your error logs.

Answer (score 2):

It does:

1. Although the Elmah.IO NuGet's latest release doesn't support
   Xamarin.Forms cross-platform logging, I have used it in my
   Android/iOS/UWP projects' exception handling separately by following instructions [here](https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-xamarin/).
2. [Here](https://elmah.io/features/xamarin-logging/) you can find out descriptions about the
   pre-release elmah.io for Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.